# Why is my XML file showing a tag like <tag/>?

Tags: xml

It's the first time I write an XML file and i want to make an app ,that                        supports registering in an xml file.
For the first person in the database i wrote the following code:

```
  if (!File.Exists("clienti.xml"))
        {
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(memStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            using (writer)
            {
                writer.WriteStartDocument();

                writer.WriteStartElement("clienti");
                writer.WriteStartElement("client" numarClienti.ToString());
                numarClienti++;


                writer.WriteStartElement("cnp");
                writer.WriteValue(textBox1.Text);
                writer.WriteEndElement();

                writer.WriteStartElement("nume");
                writer.WriteValue(textBox2.Text);
                writer.WriteEndElement();

                writer.WriteStartElement("prenume");
                writer.WriteValue(textBox3.Text);
                writer.WriteEndElement();

                writer.WriteStartElement("email");
                writer.WriteValue(textBox4.Text);
                writer.WriteEndElement();

                writer.WriteStartElement("parola");
                writer.WriteValue(textBox5.Text);
                writer.WriteEndElement();

                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
            writer.Close();

            string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memStream.ToArray());

            memStream.Close();

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("clienti.xml");
            sw.WriteLine(xml);
            sw.Close();
        }
```

The problem comes when the second person tries to register .I tried to write a code with the classes i used on the first clause of if,but i couldn't.
This is my solution:

```
{
      XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("clienti.xml");
                XElement nodPersoanaNoua = new XElement("client1");


              nodPersoanaNoua.Add(new XElement("nume"),new XAttribute("nume","Ionica"),new XElement("nume","georgica"));

                doc.Descendants("clienti").Single().Add(nodPersoanaNoua);
                doc.Save("clienti.xml");
            }
My problem is that in my document a tag like <tag/>.




<client1 nume="Ionica">
   <nume />
   <nume>georgica</nume>
   </client1>.
```

Why it appears like this ?Is it any method to write the second branch of if like in the first branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new XElement("nume")` creates an empty element with name `nume` and the markup representation of such an empty element is  `<nume/>` or `<nume></nume>` or `<nume />`. You haven't explained which result you want instead but you use a different approach with `new XElement("nume","georgica")` where you create an element with text content `<nume>georgica</nume>`.